# why the elements in the array can change value, but the value of primitive type can not change?(cannot figure out a good title, sorry)

Tags: java

Please see the code(Java):

```
public static int[] array(){
     int[]arr={0,1};
     changeArr(arr);
     return arr;
}
public static void changeArr(int[]arr){
    arr[0]=100;
    arr[1]=101;
}
```

then I print the element in arr[], I find arr[0] turns to 100, and arr[1] turns to 101, and I know that right, since the method changeArr() change the values.

However,

```
public static int m(){
   int m=0;
   changeM(m);
   return m;
}
public static void changeM(int m){
   m=100;
}
```

why the value of m does not change? If I print m, m is still 0, it does not change to 100, why?
why the elements in the array can change, but the primitive type m does not change?

Comment: Hint: what does this code do? `public static int[] array2() {int[] ar = {0, 1}; changeArr2(arr); return arr;}` `public static void changeArr2(int[] arr) {arr = new int[] {3, 4};}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java passes arguments by value. This means that a copy of the argument is made, and this copy is passed to the method. In the case of an array, what is copied is the reference (or pointer, if you prefer) to the array. So you get the following:

Before the method call:

```
arr --------> [1, 2]
```

During the method call, before the assignments:

```
arr --------> [1, 2]
               ^
               |
arr-copy -------
```

During the method call, after the assignments:

```
arr --------> [100, 101]
               ^
               |
arr-copy -------
```

After the method call:

```
arr --------> [100, 101]
```

When you pass a primitive, the primitive value itself is copied.

Before the method call:

```
m ========  0
```

During the method call, before the assignment:

```
m ========= 0


m-copy ==== 0
```

During the method call, after the assignment:

```
m ========= 0


m-copy ==== 100
```

After the method call:

```
m ========= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second case `m` passed by value, so it changes only inside the method. In the first case `arr` is passed by value, which is just reference to the array not the whole array object. So changing `arr[i]` will change outside the method. But if you do `arr = some other array` it'll be just like the the second case, changes remains inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

In Java function calls, arguments are passed by "copy-of-values".

- (1)For primitive types(int/float/long/double...), the "copy-of-values" means copies of those primitive types. Now there are 2 pieces of data: the original one in the caller and the copy one in the callee. Their contents are the same, but address(in memory) are different, so you change the copy will not affect the orignal one.
- (2)For reference types(Object/array), means copies of their references(similar to "pointer" in C/C++). Now there are 2 pieces of references, the original one in the caller and the copy one in the callee. Even they are 2 individual reference(address are different), but their content are the same(content is the address to the Object/array). So either of them is the key to access the same Object/array.

Pls see my comment below:

```
public static int[] array(){
     int[]arr={0,1};  // arr is a reference(pointer) to [0,1]
     changeArr(arr);  // copy the reference and pass to changeArr()
     return arr;
}
public static void changeArr(int[]arr){ // Get the copy of reference, the copy also point to [0,1].
    arr[0]=100;  // Use the reference as a key to change the array [0,1]
    arr[1]=101;  // Use the reference as a key to change the array [0,1]
}

public static int m(){
   int m=0;  // m is a primitive type(int), it stays in its own address(eg. A1).
   changeM(m);  // Make a copy of m(we call it m'), the content of m' is 0, but its address(A2) is different from m. Pass m' to changeM().
   return m;
}
public static void changeM(int m){  // Get m'.
   m=100;  // No matter how to change m', will not affect m, because they are individual.
}
```